# Dispatcher Invoke multi control in one delegate?

Tags: wpf

I am working on a WPF application,
I have to fetch the picasa album from google API and bind to WPF listview.

I have to bind to 2 listview and using Dispatcher.Invoke().

Below is the code snippet:

```
   private void BindPicasa()
    {
        //My custom Google helper class.
        GoogleClass google = new GoogleClass();

        ThreadStart start = delegate()
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                 new Action(delegate()
                 {
                     //Fetch the album list
                     List<AlbumClass.Album> album = google.RequestAlbum(GoogleID);

                     //bind to a 1st listview in text title.
                     ListLeftAlbum.DataContext = album;

                     //bind to a 2nd listview in thumbnail preview.
                     ListMainAlbum.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                     ListMainAlbum.DataContext = album;
                 }));
        };
        new Thread(start).Start();
    }
```

The UI will freeze when start,
However if i take out each listview and run with its own Dispatcher, it is fine, the UI responsible, but it seems not elegant way to do so.
Any recommend? Thanks you!

```
   private void BindPicasa()
    {
        //My custom Google helper class.
        GoogleClass google = new GoogleClass();

        ThreadStart start = delegate()
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                 new Action(delegate()
                 {
                     //Fetch the album list
                     List<AlbumClass.Album> album = google.RequestAlbum(GoogleID);
                 }));
            ListLeftAlbum.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                 new Action(delegate()
                 {
                     //bind to a 1st listview in text title.
                     ListLeftAlbum.DataContext = album;
                 }));
            ListMainAlbum.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                 new Action(delegate()
                 {
                     //bind to a 2nd listview in thumbnail preview.
                     ListMainAlbum.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                     ListMainAlbum.DataContext = album;
                 }));
        };
        new Thread(start).Start();
    }
```

Comment: The trick is that you do the lengthy operation (`google.RequestAlbum`) in the background *before* calling `Dispatcher.Invoke`. Otherwise you wouldn't even need a background thread.

Comment: You're not making use of the `Thread` actually, that's why UI goes unresposnsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first version  was almost right, you just need to fetch the album on the background thread instead of dispatching the request back to the ui thread

```
private void BindPicasa()
{
    //My custom Google helper class.
    GoogleClass google = new GoogleClass();

    ThreadStart start = delegate()
    {
        //Fetch the album list
        List<AlbumClass.Album> album = google.RequestAlbum(GoogleID);

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
             new Action(delegate()
             {
                 //bind to a 1st listview in text title.
                 ListLeftAlbum.DataContext = album;

                 //bind to a 2nd listview in thumbnail preview.
                 ListMainAlbum.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                 ListMainAlbum.DataContext = album;
             }));
    };
    new Thread(start).Start();
}
```